# How to add Font awesome and jQuery Link in SharePoint Master Page or any other page

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I am using SharePoint 2013, I want to use font awesome in my pages

But when I put the link in Master page or in any page, when I want to access the page it give message like: Show All content

My SharePoint has SSL for your info

Can any one tell me what is the secure way and better way I can use Font Awesome Link or jQuery Link in my pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is being loaded with securely  `https` protocol and your font awesome file is being loaded using `http` protocol.

That is why the browser is blocking the content loading of that font awesome file (It's the default behavior of browser).

You need to always click on that alert button or else if possible download the font awesome file and place into Style Library and then refer in masterpage. Here you can find the explanations how to do it: [Font Awesome EASY: Default CSS](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#default-css)

As an other alternative you can load font awesome file with `http` protocol if supported.

The same way you can do with jQuery library or any other JavaScript plugin. You just need to keep in mind the protocol should be the same wherever it is applicable.

For further details you can read this article with explanations of referencing jQuery library to SharePoint masterpage [here](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Refer-Scripts-and-CSS-Style-Sheet-in-SharePoint-2013-Visual-Web-Part-and-Master-Page.aspx).

Comment: I think, based in the question, it is the other way around: SharePoint is using HTTPS but the host supplying the font-file is not

Comment: @RobertLindgren: Thanks, I have updated the answer. Though it is almost same!